# not able to include functions from shared library to v8 engine

Tags: c++, c, v8, shared-libraries

i am unable to include functions from shared object to v8. The code for shared object is

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace v8;

//extern "C" typedef v8::String::Utf8Value utf8;

extern "C" void foo(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    printf("foo");
}

extern "C" void bar(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        printf("bar");
}

extern "C" void yolo(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    bool first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length(); i++) {
        static   v8::HandleScope handle_scope(args.GetIsolate());
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
        // utf8 str(args[i]);
        //   v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[i]);
        //   const char* cstr = *str ? *str : "<string conversion failed>";
        //  printf("%s",cstr);
        //    sock_output.append(cstr);
  }
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

and the code for importing is

```
void *handle;
handle = dlopen("./plugins/libutil.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (!handle)
{
    printf("The error is %s", dlerror());
}

typedef void (*destroy_t)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);

ifstream file("./plugins/libutil.txt");
if(!file.is_open())
    cout<<"Error opening file";
else{
    string str;
    destroy_t destroy;
    while (getline(file,str))
    {
        const char* temp = str.c_str();
        destroy=(destroy_t)dlsym(handle,temp);
        if (!destroy)
        {
            cout<<"The error is %s"<<dlerror();
        }

        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, temp), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, destroy));
    }
}
file.close();
```

can someone please tell me how to properly include a functions from shared objects in v8

Comment: Are you trying to `dlsym` C++ functions? If so, then google "name mangling".

Comment: Error messages are not posted, voting to close. In the future, print not only the error message itself, bit all relevant information that led to the error, in this case the function name and the library name.

Comment: i added extern "C" so i think name mangling is taken care of. also as for the relevant info i just want to know on how to include functions in v8 dynamically from shared object